# Using Elasticsearch.Net/NEST to search parent documents based on child attributes, where parent/child documents are stored separately

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I would like to use Elasticsearch.Net/NEST to search related documents. For example, I have:

```
Person:

id name address_id
-- ---- ----------
1  John 1
2  Mary 2

Address:

id city
-- ------
1  Boston
2  Berlin
```

I'd like to store the Person and Address documents separately, and do queries where I return Person documents based on Address fields. For example, return all documents for people living in Boston. I've seen some examples in the Elaticsearch documentation using mapping and parent/child directives, but nothing for Elasticsearch.Net/NEST. Any code samples or pointers would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a small snippet where the address is the parent

EDIT:
Create the index:

```
var indicesOperationResponse = _client.CreateIndex(ci => ci.Index("test")
            .AddMapping<Address>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
            .AddMapping<Person>(m => m.MapFromAttributes().SetParent<Address>()));
```

Index documents:

```
var bulkResponse = _client.Bulk(b => b
            .Index<Address>(bd => bd.Object(new Address { Name = "Tel Aviv", Id = 1 }).Index("test"))
            .Index<Person>(bd => bd.Index("test").Object(new Person {Id = 5, Address = 1, Name = "Me"}).Parent(1)));
```

And search by parent

```
var searchResponse = _client.Search<Person>(s => s
        .Query(q=>q.MatchAll())
        .Filter(q => q
            .HasParent<Address>(c => c
                .Query(cq => cq.Match(m=>m.OnField(t => t.Name).Query("Tel Aviv"))))));
```

Comment: Thanks. The query looks like what I need, but how do I properly add the Person and Address documents to the index?

Comment: @BillyP. - I added the create index and index docs to the snippet

Comment: Actually, there's a problem. I also get "Me" returned when I search for "Tokyo".

Comment: Never mind, I found my problem. Your solution works great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you index a single child document? `_client.Index(somePerson)` is the only way to index a document individually as far as i know. There is no way to specify `.Parent(parentId)` after that.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best place to look is at the NEST Unit Tests.

- [Fluent Mapping Full Example Tests](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/tree/1.x/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/Map/FluentMappingFullExampleTests.cs) - Includes an example of setting Parent relationship.
- [Has Parent Query](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/tree/1.x/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Search/Query/Singles/HasParentQueryJson.cs)
- [Has Child Query](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/tree/1.x/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Search/Query/Singles/HasParentQueryJson.cs)
- [Top Children Query](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/tree/1.x/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Search/Query/Singles/TopChildrenQueryJson.cs)

Also on the [Nest Documentation Site](http://nest.azurewebsites.com) there is a small snippet for running a [has_child](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/query/has-child.html) query. (Pretty much the same as the unit test)

Comment: Those links helped, but it's not clear how to add the documents to the index. Any pointers there?