# In Nest, how do I specify a child document's parent document while indexing?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

`Product` and `Company` are in a many-to-one child-parent relationship:

```
[ElasticType(Name = "product", IdProperty = "ProductId")]
internal class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

[ElasticType(Name = "company", IdProperty = "CompanyId")]
public class Company
{
   public int CompanyId { get; set; }
   public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

In the mapping of `Product`, I did:

```
Func<PutMappingDescriptor<Product>, PutMappingDescriptor<Product>> descriptor = m => m
               .MapFromAttributes()
               .AllField(a => a.Enabled(false))
               .SetParent<Company>();
```

I created a parent and child:

```
var company = new Company {
    CompanyId = 1,
    CompanyName = "XYZ Company"
};

var p2 = new Product{
    ProductId = 2,
    Title = "ABC Product"
};

es.Index(company);
```

The problem is then, how do I index `p2`? With only the `Index` method, I can only do `es.Index(p2)`. But where do I indicate that `p2` should be indexed under the parent `company`?

**Basically I wanted a NEST solution to `PUT /myindex/product/2?parent=1`**.

The closest answer I found so far is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23953742/1124270. But the answer uses bulk inserts like the following where you have a `.Parent` method in the chaining to specify the parent's ID:

```
var bulkResponse = _client.Bulk(b => b
            .Index<Address>(bd => bd.Object(new Address { Name = "Tel Aviv", Id = 1 }).Index("test"))
            .Index<Person>(bd => bd.Index("test").Object(new Person {Id = 5, Address = 1, Name = "Me"}).Parent(1)));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for `PUT /myindex/product/2?parent=1` request. 
You can do this in the NEST in a such way:

```
var indexResponse = client.Index(p2, descriptor => descriptor
    .Parent(company.CompanyId.ToString()));
```

which generates below request to elasticsearch

```
StatusCode : 400,
Method : PUT,
Url : http : //localhost:9200/indexname/product/2?parent=1,
Request : {
    "productId" : 2,
    "title" : "ABC Product"
}
```